# how to unit test view model class that is not public in wpf project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm

I'm creating a unit test project using MS test Framework for a simple wpf appilcation with MVVM archtecture.

Here is the source code under "ViewModel" directory

ViewModelBase.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace HPCEMConnectionWizardWin.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

ViewModelMain.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using HPCEMConnectionWizardWin.Model;
using System.Security;

namespace HPCEMConnectionWizardWin.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelMain : ViewModelBase
    {
        string _USB;
        public string USB
        {
            get
            {
                return _USB;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_USB != value)
                {
                    _USB = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("USB");
                }
            }
        }

        string _URL;
        public string URL
        {
            get
            {
                return _URL;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_URL != value)
                {
                    _URL = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("URL");
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Here is my unit test code:

UnitTest1.cs:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using HPCEMConnectionWizardWin;
using HPCEMConnectionWizardWin.ViewModel;

namespace UnitTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void USBTest()
        {
            bool didFire = false;
            ViewModelMain _viewModelMain = new ViewModelMain(); //Error CS0122
            _viewModelMain.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                didFire = true;
                Assert.AreEqual("USB", e.PropertyName);
                Assert.AreEqual("Test", _viewModelMain.USB);
            };
            _viewModelMain.USB = "Test";
            Assert.IsTrue(didFire);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void URLTest()
        {
            bool didFire = false;
            ViewModelMain _viewModelMain = new ViewModelMain();
            _viewModelMain.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                didFire = true;
                Assert.AreEqual("URL", e.PropertyName);
                Assert.AreEqual("Test", _viewModelMain.URL);
            };
            _viewModelMain.URL = "Test";
            Assert.IsTrue(didFire);
        }
    }
}
```

questions:

1. I have to make "ViewModelMain" a public class to avoid the following error:

   Error   CS0122  'ViewModelMain' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Do I have to make that ViewModel class public for unit test? I found many ViewModelclasses in other projects are not public? Is there any risk to change these classes into public ones?

2. I ran the these test code on azure pipeline and two tests method passed and code coverage is 3.51% (pretty low). Now I like to raise the code coverage rate, ss there any code under "View" and "Model" I can do unit test for other than the classes in the "ViewModel"?

This project is a simple GUI app for user to copy certificate file to you system folder from USB drive or URL, in the code of "View", there are functions for download, copy, and validate the certificate file, but I guess they are not business logic and not fit to do the unit test, right?

Most time I got following error when I click "Create Unit Tests"(context menu item of MS test) for code under "View" and "Model".

```
Create Unit Tests is supported only within a public class or a public method.
```

Comment: Use the `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(...)}` attribute.

Comment: BTW, your unit-tests won't work as-expected because you aren't setting-up an Event Dispatcher for your tests. In WPF+XAML+etc, the `PropertyChanged` event is **not** intended to be handled (and reacted-to) immediately - instead the Dispatcher will coalesce and debounce events, and prevent things like infinite-loops (e.g. by changing 1 property inside an event-listener).

Comment: `internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)` <-- This should be `private`, not `internal`. Only the actual implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` should be raising the events, but by making it `internal` you're allowing other types to raise the event when they shouldn't be able to.

Comment: `RaisePropertyChanged` must not be `private` but `protected`. Otherwise it could not be called from view model classes that derive from ViewModelBase.

Comment: @Clemens I think viewmodel inheritance is a bad idea, overall.

Comment: Use reflection.

Comment: Thanks you guys for point out the problem in the ViewModel classes. Is there any problem in the unit test method I wrote? 
This project is a simple GUI app for user to copy certificate file to you system folder from USB drive or URL, in the code of "View", there are functions for download, copy, and validate the certificate file, but I guess they are not business logic and not fit to do the unit test, right?